# Router::redirect() deprecated

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.8

`Router::redirect() is deprecated. Use Router::scope() and RouteBuilder::redirect() instead.`

The message gives some lead, but did not find direct answer in docs.

Direct switching to `RouteBuilder::redirect()` instead not possible as it is not static function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem in the end. Easy once you read `Router::scope()` usage in docs properly and notice you get `RouteBuilder` object as param for the function.

Docs: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/routing.html#quick-tour

---

Original (deprecated)

```
Router::redirect('/old', '/new');
```

New

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    $routes->redirect('/old', '/new');
});
```